# The request to the controller does not pass ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I just started learning MVC. And I think maybe I didn't quite understand how to add new api controllers.
I added a new api controller using Entity to work with a new table in the database.
The first api controller works as it should.

First controller retunr jsom file as it should.
And here is his code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestReact.Models;

namespace TestReact.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ChildrenController : ControllerBase
{
private readonly ClinicContext _context;

public ChildrenController(ClinicContext context)
{
_context = context;
}

// GET: api/Children
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Child>>> GetChildren()
{

var test = _context.Mkb10s.ToList();


return await _context.Children
.ToListAsync();
}

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutChild(int id, Child child)
{
if (id != child.ChildId)
{
return BadRequest();
}

_context.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;

try
{
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
if (!ChildExists(id))
{
return NotFound();
}
else
{
throw;
}
}

return NoContent();
}

// POST: api/Children
//To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Child>> PostChild(Child child)
{
//Console.WriteLine(child);
_context.Children.Add(child);
try
{
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException)
{
if (ChildExists(child.ChildId))
{
return Conflict();
}
else
{
throw;
}
}

return CreatedAtAction("GetChild", new { id = child.ChildId }, child);
}

// DELETE: api/Children/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteChild(int id)
{
var child = await _context.Children.FindAsync(id);
if (child == null)
{
return NotFound();
}

_context.Children.Remove(child);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

return NoContent();
}

private bool ChildExists(int id)
{
return _context.Children.Any(e => e.ChildId == id);
}
}
}
```

And is the request to the second controller return:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <base href="/" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>TestReact</title>
    <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

His code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestReact.Models;

namespace TestReact.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class Mkb10Controller : ControllerBase
{
private readonly ClinicContext _context;

public Mkb10Controller(ClinicContext context)
{
_context = context;
}

// GET: api/Mkb10
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Mkb10>>> GetMkb10s()
{
if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
{
return NotFound();
}
return await _context.Mkb10s.ToListAsync();
}

// GET: api/Mkb10/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Mkb10>> GetMkb10(int id)
{
if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
{
return NotFound();
}
var mkb10 = await _context.Mkb10s.FindAsync(id);

if (mkb10 == null)
{
return NotFound();
}

return mkb10;
}

// PUT: api/Mkb10/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutMkb10(int id, Mkb10 mkb10)
{
if (id != mkb10.Id)
{
return BadRequest();
}

_context.Entry(mkb10).State = EntityState.Modified;

try
{
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
if (!Mkb10Exists(id))
{
return NotFound();
}
else
{
throw;
}
}

return NoContent();
}

// POST: api/Mkb10
// To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Mkb10>> PostMkb10(Mkb10 mkb10)
{
if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
{
return Problem("Entity set 'ClinicContext.Mkb10s' is null.");
}
_context.Mkb10s.Add(mkb10);
try
{
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch (DbUpdateException)
{
if (Mkb10Exists(mkb10.Id))
{
return Conflict();
}
else
{
throw;
}
}

return CreatedAtAction("GetMkb10", new { id = mkb10.Id }, mkb10);
}

// DELETE: api/Mkb10/5
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMkb10(int id)
{
if (_context.Mkb10s == null)
{
return NotFound();
}
var mkb10 = await _context.Mkb10s.FindAsync(id);
if (mkb10 == null)
{
return NotFound();
}

_context.Mkb10s.Remove(mkb10);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

return NoContent();
}

private bool Mkb10Exists(int id)
{
return (_context.Mkb10s?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
}
}
}
```

And the Program.cs code

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestReact.Models;
using TestReact.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

string connection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

//builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ClinicContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
// The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");


app.Run();
```

Comment: You've provided a lot of code, but I suspect you have more here than what is necessary to demonstrate your issue. Please review [mcve] for guidance on how to eliminate the unnecessary parts and be left with the minimal amount of code needed that still reproduces your issue. Secondly: what exactly is the problem? You haven't give us a clear statement, other than saying "the request to the controller does not pass" in the title - with no clue what you mean by that. Please be specific in describing what behavior you're expecting and what you're getting, and what URL's you're accessing.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @mason, I really added too much code, I just can't add pictures because of low karma, it would be easier with them.The problem is that my second controller(Mkb10) should return json data, but returns a standard 404 error, and I think that the request simply does not reach this controller

Comment: @RahulSharma, I am trying to get data in json format

Comment: @xodiz For your `API` or for your `View` to be displayed?

Comment: @RahulSharma, the request will come from my frontend to react.js, then react receives json and processes it (mapping to a table, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

@xodiz

Firstly, Based on your codes,you are trying with SPA pattern not MVC pattern .If you want to try with MVC projects, you could follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

None of your controller returns Html codes (ViewResult),so i think the second time you visit a controller with wrong path and it returns the html codes of `index.html`For you've called `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");` it works when none of the route registed match your path,it fall back to `index.html` instead of return 404

And the Route Attribute like `[Route("api/[controller]")]` would override the route you registed in program.cs:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
name: "default",
pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

For example, if you try with `/api/Children` you would receive json data, if you try with `"/Children/GetChildren"` you would receive the html codes of index.html

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) related routing for more details

Comment: I understand that a 404 error will return if the address is not correct. But I send a request to my second controller (Mkb10) which should return json, but I get error 404, although I write the address "api/Mkb10" (I did it in postman, I would like to add a picture for clarity, but unfortunately I can't because of low karma)

Comment: Have you debugged?if   return NotFound()  was executed;  it would also return 404,make sure  _context.Mkb10s !=null

Comment: If you still have problems ,you could upload a minimal example that could reproduce your error to github

Comment: @RuikaiFeng No, please don't encourage that. It's perfectly possible to provide a [mcve] to Stack Overflow. We should not encourage people to go off site, because off site resources don't stick around and then we're left with a useless question.